# How to configure www. CNAME

Tags: dns

This question must be so basic that I am bewildered why I cannot find a clear answer.

I want to configure my DNS for a new domain name. I configure the A record with the IP address of my host server. domain.com works fine. But how do I configure the CNAME to create the www. alias? It won't accept an IP address, and aliasing it to domain.com does not seem to work.

Comment: A `CNAME` pointing to `domain.com` should work if there's an `A` record on `domain.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following record should work:

```
www IN CNAME domain.com.
```

Make sure you have the `.` at the end of `domain.com.`. Names that don't end with `.` automatically get the origin appended, so it would be treated as `domain.com.domain.com.`.